# How to access a json inside a class tag

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

I want to know how can I target this data-ft Json to use the data inside it?

Here is the class I want to extract that json form:

```
<div class="_4-u2 mbm _5jmm _5pat _5v3q _4-u8"    
   data-ft="{"top_level_post_id":"1543779512511249","fbfeed_location":36}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found the way is by using getattribute

Comment: Interesting - the HTML in your original post is invalid HTML, and `data-ft` will just contain the string `"{"`.  Are you sure it's working?

Comment: that what the facebook returns i just copied and paste it but i found the solution by using the get attribute property